# "_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance" in python's tkinter when trying to modify object coordinates with Canvas.coords()

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make a canvas with some items that can move and rotate, to do this, i have functions to modify the coordinates, however i am having trouble with moving the objects. I am trying to use the coords function to change the coordinates of each object.

the current bit of code that is raising the error is:

```python
count = 1
for part in self._createdpartlist:
    self.coords(part, self._partlist[count].coordinates)
    count += 1
```

self is a Canvas object i created. with createdpartlist containing id's of created parts in canvas (all 4 sided polygons) and partlist being a list of objects that have coordinates that are returned in the form of [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3), (x4, y4)]

however when i try to run it, i get the error;

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "340)]"
```

(in this case 340 is the y4 coordinate)

I dont exactly know what it means by bad screen distance, and cant really figure out whats going wrong or if i am using coords function incorrectly.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Edit: i get this error when i make a new file only containing this.

```python
from tkinter import *

coordinates = [(330,230), (350,230), (350,340), (330,340)]
new_coords = [(340,245), (340,260), (400,260), (400,245)]

c = Canvas()

shape = c.create_polygon(coordinates)

c.coords(shape, new_coords)
```

the error comes up with "245)]" instead of "340)]" in this instance

Comment: It looks like your coordinates are stored as strings. In your loop can you try `print(self._partlist[count].coordinates)` and see what it is?

Comment: that seemed to be most of the problems when i googled the error. however nothing in the code is ever specified as a string, and i can call upon same list of coordinates and use them as numbers when i test it in python shell, so i dont believe that they are strings. 
when printed it comes up [(330, 230), (350, 230), (350, 340), (330, 340)]

Comment: Maybe they are being converted somewhere unexpectedly? Did you try investigating the data  in the loop? I understand the error might just be formatted strangely but it looks like something has converted the list of tuples into a string and maybe split on commas.

Comment: i have looked through all of the functions the coordinates go through when made, but cant find anything, even printing out self._partlist[0].coordinates returns the list of number coordinates, so the only way i could understand them becoming strings is within the coords function.

Comment: oh and depending on which loop you are referring too, the for loop is only what is written above so there isnt anything else happening there, and in the tkinter mainloop, the coordinates are entered directly as numbers and then are modified by functions which i have checked so they dont become strings

Comment: Interesting! If you can make a minimum working example that creates a polygon then moves it with this error i will try to figure it out. Sorry I don't know exactly what is going on.

Comment: I added an edit with a simplified version of the code, i believe it must just be me using coords function incorrectly

Comment: Also are you sure you want to start indexing at 1 instead of zero? I'm not sure how your new coords data is stored but that looks like a potential bug.

Comment: Ah i forgot to mention that, index 0 is an oval object rather than a polygon object, so it required a different argument thus i skipped over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this? I will try it later when I am not on mobile.

```
import itertools
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk


# from itertools recipes: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
def flatten(list_of_lists):
    """Flatten one level of nesting"""
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_of_lists)


coordinates = [(330,230), (350,230), (350,340), (330,340)]
new_coords = [(340,245), (340,260), (400,260), (400,245)]
c = tk.Canvas()
shape = c.create_polygon(coordinates)
c.coords(shape, *flatten(new_coords))
```

If that works then try:

```
for i, part in enumerate(self._createdpartlist):
    self.coords(part, *flatten(self._partlist[i+1].coordinates))
```

Comment: You are a legend, i tried flattening it earlier, but it turns out i needed to add the * before the argument. thanks so much

Comment: Great! In case anybody reading this wonders, the `*....` unpacks the sequence so that it is equivalent to calling `coords(part, x0, y0, x1, y1)` instead of `coords(part, (x0, y0, x1, y1))`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into `_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance` when trying Pypy3 5.5.0-alpha.

Changing coordinate lists into tuples helped.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
spCoords = [(20, 20), (20, 30), (30, 30)]

tmpCoords = [(x[0], x[1] - 1) for x in spCoords] + [(x[0], x[1] + 1) for x in reversed(spCoords)]

spCoords = []

for x in tmpCoords:
    spCoords.append( x[0] )
    spCoords.append( x[1] )

print( *spCoords )
    
scanvas.coords(pcPoly, *spCoords)
```