# Tkinter grid manager bad screen distance

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I tried using the Grid manager and wanted to place 4 buttons in 2 rows and 2 columns with this code:

```py
button1 = Button(window, wrap="Button1", width=10)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(window, wrap="Button2", width=10)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
button2.pack()

button3 = Button(window, wrap="Button3", width=10)
button3.grid(row=1, column=0)
button3.pack()

button4 = Button(window, wrap="Button4", width=10)
button4.grid(row=1, column=1)
button4.pack()
```

And I got this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "Button1"
```

I don't know what a screen distance is and don't know how to fix a bad one. Can someone please help me there, please?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32450773/16136190) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45887965/tkinter-bad-screen-distance-10-0) help?

Comment: What do you think `wrap="Button1"` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

---

```py
button1=tkinter.Button(window, text="button1", width=10) # create button 1
button1.grid(row=1,column=0) # arrange button 1 place


button2=tkinter.Button(window, text="button2", width=10) # create button 2
button2.grid(row=2,column=0) # arrange button 2 place

button3=tkinter.Button(window, text="button3", width=10) # create button 3
button3.grid(row=1,column=2) # arrange button 3 place

button4=tkinter.Button(window, text="button4", width=10) # create button 4
button4.grid(row=2,column=2) # arrange button 4 place
```

---

### What to do to fix that?

---

You need to remove the command called `button1.pack()` and from other buttons too, so it should be as the code attached. Also change `warp` to `text` when creating button.

Comment: Also, one optional thing which you can do, is set all buttons to ``width=10, height=10`` which makes them look much better when executing the code

Answer (score 0):

Change `wrap` to `text` and remove the `.pack()` as you have already used `.grid()`

```
button1 = Button(window, text="Button1", width=10)
button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

button2 = Button(window, text="Button2", width=10)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1)

button3 = Button(window, text="Button3", width=10)
button3.grid(row=1, column=0)

button4 = Button(window, text="Button4", width=10)
button4.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry,but that generated a different Error: `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack`

Comment: That error is usually caused by using `.pack()` and `.grid()` on the same object. If this isn't all of your code look through your code and see where you've used both for the same object and remove the `.pack()`

Comment: do you mean all objects in my script? or only the 4 buttons? I inly used .grid on the 4 buttons

Comment: I'm sorry,but that didnt work...

Comment: Did you put anything else in the `window` with `.pack()` ? Or just the buttons?

Comment: I replaced every .pack() with a .grid() And got this Error '''_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-fill": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky'''

Comment: It might be easier to create a `LabelFrame`, put the buttons in the LabelFrame (with the grid format then pack the frame to `window` along with the other objects. Have you tried the code in the answer separate from the rest of your code as it worked in my end